# Is it possible to confirm the phone number via voice call in cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito

We are looking at creating signup form for cognito. As part of registration we require the user to verify the phone number. We would like users to use cell phone and home phone to be used. To enable this functionality we need to send the code via voice call. I have seen this option in google idp. Is it possible to confirm the phone number via voice call in cognito?